# How do you run Cleanmgr.exe remotely?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm having some trouble getting Clean Manager on Windows 10 to run remotely. I've seen a few different things were you can edit the registry and modify the `/sageset` or `/sagerun` to be specific things then run it remotely, but it seems no matter what I do the CleanMgr runs locally on my machine rather than running remotely.

I believe this is the closest I've gotten to get it to run remotely... It seems to still just run locally on my machine though.

Any ideas?

( All variables are set before this portion of the script, this is just a small portion of what's going on that I'm stuck on )

```
## Starts cleanmgr.exe
Function Start-CleanMGR {
    Write-Host "Please provide your A-Account details to continue with this cleanup."
    $creds = Get-Credential
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computername -Credential $creds
    try {
        $cleanmgr = Start-Process -Credential $creds -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cleanmgr.exe" -ArgumentList '/verylowdisk' -Wait -Verbose
        if ($cleanmgr) {
            Write-Host "Clean Manager ran successfully!                                                                   " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
            Write-Host "[DONE]" -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
        }
    }
    catch [System.Exception] {
        Write-host "Cleanmgr is not installed! To use this portion of the script you must install the following windows features:" -NoNewline -ForegroundColor DarkGray
        Write-host "[ERROR]" -ForegroundColor Red -BackgroundColor Black
    }
} Start-CleanMGR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell always runs in the user context of the user who started the session. This is by design.

You can not run a GUI based application remotely using PowerShell. It is a Windows security boundary.

To run GUI apps, someone must be logged on, and you cannot use PowerShell to run code as the logged-on user.

You are also prompting for info, so, someone must be logged on.

If you are expecting a user to prived info, then you need to:

1. Create the script
2. Deploy the script to the user's machine or a files share from wich it
   can be ran
3. Tell the user how to do it or create a batch file they would double
   click to run the PowerShell script

Or

Set the script to run as a scheduled task at log on or at some point during the day, as the user credentials.

Variables have the scope and you cannot use local variables in a remote context unless they are scoped for that.

> [About Remote Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7)
>
> Using local variables
>
> You can use local variables in remote commands, but the variable must
>   be defined in the local session.
>
> Beginning in PowerShell 3.0, you can use the Using scope modifier to
>   identify a local variable in a remote command.
>
> The syntax of Using is as follows:

```
$Using:<VariableName>
```

Still, the remote variable is not something you will do in your use case since you cannot do what you are after natively with PowerShell. You'll need a 3rdP tool like MS SysInternals [PSExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) to run code remotely as the logged-on user.

> Using PsExec
>
> Usage: psexec [\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p
>   psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c
>   executable [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-][-a n,n,...] cmd
>   [arguments]
>
> -i    Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the
>   process runs in the console session.
>
> -u    Specifies optional user name for login to remote computer.

Comment: Thank you so much postanote! This is great information to have and I greatly appreciate it. It makes sense from a security stand point as well. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use `Invoke-Command`

```
Function Start-CleanMGR ($computername, $creds) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computername -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {
        try {
            $cleanmgr = Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cleanmgr.exe" -ArgumentList '/verylowdisk' -Wait -Verbose
            if ($cleanmgr) {
                return "Clean Manager ran successfully!"
            }
        }
        catch [System.Exception] {
            return "Cleanmgr is not installed! To use this portion of the script you must install the following windows features:"
        }
    }
}

Start-CleanMGR -computername "remotehost" -creds (Get-Credential)
```

Comment: I tried this in a Windows Server 2016 RDS and the process hangs forever

Comment: @Grasshopper
Try removing -Wait switch

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In that case invoke-command returns immediately but cleanmgr doesn't run on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you execute cleanmgr.exe under a user account that has local admin rights, everything will work. Running cleanmgr.exe under the SYSTEM account, E.G. running from the Run Script Tool in SCCM/MECM will not work unless the script first opens a separate shell (DOS/PS) under a user that has local admin rights...even the cleanmgr.exe /verylowdisk will not run under the SYSTEM account.