# Run Cleanmgr on remote PC as System user

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-remoting

So i'm trying to run CleanMgr via powershell on a remote computer. Since CleanMgr has a GUI Powershell cannot run it directly, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231719/how-do-you-run-cleanmgr-exe-remotely#:%7E:text=you%20can%20not%20run%20a%20gui%20based%20application%20remotely%20using%20powershell.%20it%20is%20a%20windows%20security%20boundary.)

If you do this then CleanMgr will hang forever waiting for user input. So this means we have to approach this differently.

I tried several approaches, see below. But non of them works like i would. It still hangs OR runs attached from powershell giving no feedback when done.

Simply put i want to run (remotely) CleanMgr on our Office PC's from my PC (Domain Admin).

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerOBJ -ScriptBlock {

    # Create registry values
    Write-Host "Setup keys..."
    $volumeCaches = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches"
    foreach ($key in $volumeCaches) {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path "$($key.PSPath)" -Name StateFlags0333 -Value 2
    }

    # Execute Disk Cleanup Tool (cleanmgr.exe)
    #Write-Host 'Starting CleanMgr.exe...'


    
    Attempt 1:
    Start-Process -FilePath "CleanMgr.exe" -ArgumentList '/sagerun:333' -NoNewWindow

    Attempt 2:
    Start-Process -FilePath "CleanMgr.exe" -ArgumentList '/sagerun:333' -WindowStyle Hidden

    Attempt 3:
    Invoke-WmiMethod -Class Win32_Process -Name "Create" -ArgumentList 'CleanMgr.exe /sagerun:333'

    Attempt 4:
    C:\temp\PsExec.exe \\$ComputerOBJ CleanMgr.exe /sagerun:333

    Attempt 5:
    $A = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "cleanmgr.exe" -Argument '/sagerun:333'
    $T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (get-date).AddSeconds(1); $t.EndBoundary = (get-date).AddSeconds(60).ToString('s')
    $S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -StartWhenAvailable -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter 00:00:30
    Register-ScheduledTask -Force -user SYSTEM -TaskName "Run CleanMgr" -Action $A -Trigger $T -Settings $S
    



    #Wait until Clean is done.
    Write-Host 'Waiting for CleanMgr and DismHost processes to complete...'
    Get-Process -Name cleanmgr, dismhost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Wait-Process    
  
    # Remove the previously created registry values
    Write-Host "Cleanmgr completed, now deleting keys"
    $volumeCaches = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches"
    foreach ($key in $volumeCaches) {
        Remove-ItemProperty -Path "$($key.PSPath)" -Name StateFlags0333 -Force
    }    
}
```

Comment: But it needs to have some provided input?

Comment: No inputs, completely silent.

Comment: I have the same problem. I believe the problem is that it hangs when it's unable to create a GUI window, but I still haven't figured a way around that.